# Where does user_id in get_user(user_id) come from?

Tags: django

I've read that an authentication backend needs to implement the methods  `get_user(user_id)` and `authenticate(request, **credentials)`. Now, `user_id` in `get_user(user_id)` must, according to the docs, be a primary key of the user model, and the method must return the user object corresponding to the `user_id`.

My question is, where does the `user_id` argument come from? Is it the username/email/whatever that is entered by the user upon authentication? And if so, why does it have to be a primary key? Why can't I be free to find the intended user in any way I see fit, inside of my `get_user()` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the default user model, the primary key is an [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), and won't be the username/email you use to log in. These log-in credentials are passed to `authenticate`, not to `get_user`.

When you log in, Django stores the primary key of the user in the session. For each request, the authentication middleware calls `get_user()` with this primary key, and sets `request.user` to the logged-in user.